# How to properly start and shutdown Tango repeatedly during app lifetime in Unity3D?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

In our app we need to enable / disable the phone camera and Tango on user request.

I currently use the `TangoApplication.Startup()` and `TangoApplication.Shutdown()` functions to do that. The first time I launch Tango, it works fine, then I shutdown it and launch it again, without quitting the app, only to see the connection screen holding forever (the "hold tight" screen).

I can't find the exact procedure for starting / shutting manually Tango in the documentation, so I am asking here.

I am using Tango Version 1.53 / Hopak and Unity Version 5.5.0f3.

Comment: Make sure you destroy all active objects, also reload the scene

Comment: Works fine, thanks !
It's a bit brutal though. No workaround ?

Comment: I think its because the app is not re-initialized when minimized and opened again. What probably happens is that `Tango` is looking for its hardware which is already in use by the app. There could be a workaround, I'm currently not aware of.

Comment: Destroying and instantiating the `TangoManager` and `TangoCamera` GameObjects alone seems to work, no need to reload the scene in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had kind of the same problem with my app. What I find out is that the tango application is initializing the tango camera in its Awake function (called only one time in its life cycle), so if at some point the camera is destroyed, then you will be stucked in the "hold tight" screen at the next start up because the camera reference will be null.

At least that's what happened to me, and I fixed this by making sure that the tango manager is destroyed and re-initialized when needed (this can be done by reloading the scene or destroying and instanciating the prefab manually).

Reminder: to know exactly what's going on while you are stucked in the "hold tight" screen, if you are on windows, you can run your app with the device plugged to the computer, and run this command in cmd.exe `adb logcat -s Unity`
(I don't know for mac and Linux but you probably have the same things)